# JTable and DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a table that gets information from my local MySQL server. It reads the data very well and post it on GUI.

My question is , how can I refresh my table when I change my table command, for example:

```
private String sql = "select * from profildb.tbl_detailed";  //to
private String sql = "select * from profildb.tbl_detailed where Y.."; //this
```

This action will be handled in my Button Action Listener ;

```
    JButton btnOK = new JButton("");
    btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            if( (tfBirinci.getText().isEmpty() || tfBirinci.getText() == null) && (tfIkinci.getText().isEmpty() || tfIkinci.getText() == null ))
            {
                taLog.setText("Database alani bos birakilamaz...\n");
            }
            else if ( (!(tfBirinci.getText().isEmpty() )) && (tfIkinci.getText().isEmpty() || tfIkinci.getText() == null ) )
            {
                sql = ("SELECT * FROM " + tfBirinci.getText());
                taLog.setText("Komut elde edildi : " + sql + "\n");
                System.out.println("aaaa " + tfBirinci.getText());
                //anaFrame.dispose();
                //databaseHistoryCalistir(); doesnt work
            }
            else if ( ( !(tfBirinci.getText().isEmpty() ) &&  !(tfBirinci.getText() == null) )  && ( !(tfIkinci.getText().isEmpty() ) && !(tfBirinci.getText() == null) ) )
            {
                sql = ("SELECT * FROM " + tfBirinci.getText() + " WHERE " + tfIkinci.getText());
                taLog.setText("Komut elde edildi : " + sql + "\n" );
                System.out.println("bbbb " + tfBirinci.getText());
                //anaFrame.dispose();
                //databaseHistoryCalistir(); doesnt work
            }else 
                taLog.setText("Lütfen Database alanini doldurunuz, aksi taktirde komut elde edilemez...\n");
        }
    });
```

So , what I need to implement for ONLY update the table when I change the statement of my string ?

Thanks in advance. (It would be awesome to give an example about DefaultTableModel)

Edit , You can see my full code here : http://pastebin.com/eQCJVuKn

Comment: What have your tried with `DefaultTableModel` so far?

Comment: Couldn't you create a new DefaultTableModel with the new dataset and set it to the JTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) use [Table from Database by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/)

2) use one of `ResultsetTableModel`

3) call SQL statement from `Runnable#Thread`, but output to the `XxxTableModel` must be inside `invokeLater`, more in the [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) about `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`

4) call SQL statement from [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), then output from `progress()`, `publish()` or `done()` should be on EDT

5) `DefaultTableModel` doesn't required override methods `fireXxxTableXxx`, all of them are correctly implemented

6) difference betweens logics `Table from Database (ResultsetTableModel)` and `Runnable#Thread(SwingWorker)` is

- `Table from Database (ResultsetTableModel)` calling all updates on EDT, then GUI waiting for all event are done, during loading data from database is GUI unresponsible or freeze
- `Runnable#Thread(SwingWorker)` all updates are from backgourng task and GUI is resposible for Mouse and Keyboard events,

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer sir. I am going to try this but first, I have to understand the `Runnable#Thread` and `EDT` , It seems complex but I assume its not.:) Thanks again.

Comment: for application that haven't production character you can use `Table from Database`, basically all todays `Databases interpreters` returns `small SQL statements` immediatelly, only `Queries that returns thousands rows` can take long time, or very `complicated SQL statements` ...., most hardiest event is by default only opening for `Database Connection`

Comment: I understand, thank you very much. Started to make some research and hope I'll handle this. Thanks again. :)